# Using the defaut application credentials to access the Google Play API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-developer-api

I'm building an appengine app that requires access to the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/). I've seen in the [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/java) that it's possible to authenticate using a service account in addition to Oauth.

Is there any chance this could work with the default service account without having to generate a json key ? That would make the setup a bit easier.

**Edit**: be more explicit about not using a json key but really using the default application credentials instead.

Answer (score 1):

- For App Engine **Standard** environment:

  You can generate a Service Account key file from default service
  account. Follow the link [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/java) you provided, then click on
  the [link](https://console.developers.google.com/) shown in the "Getting Started" section, you'll get in
  the Google Developer Console. If logged in with the correct account
  (you should see your project name at the top), then go to Credentials
  -> Create credentials -> Service Account key. In the service account dropdown list, choose "App Engine Default Service Account", choose
  JSON as key type and you should be good to go to follow the last
  instructions on the Github [page](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/java#first-request-using-oauth2-service-accounts).
- For App Engine **Flexible** environment:

  The default service account isn't listed in the Service Account page, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/service-account). You can't generate a service account key with it. You'd need to use a custom service account.

Comment: Indeed, I can generate a key for the default service account. My question was more along the lines of *not* generating a key at all. Datastore, bigquery and other cloud APIs just work out of the box without any key needed.